# Can r.js resolve dependency installed with npm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, r.js

I've install r.js from npm with `npm install requirejs`.

I'm expecting this function to produce some output to console, while running it with `node main.js`:

```
// main.js
var requirejs = require('requirejs');

requirejs.optimize({
    baseUrl: STATIC_PATH + 'js',
    nodeRequire: require,
    include: ['a', 'b'],
    out: function(text) {
        console.log(text);
    }
});
```

And modules A and B are defined as following:

```
// a.js

define(['b'], function($) {
    console.log('A');
});
```

I know from requirejs docs that it could handle modules installed with npm, so here I'm trying to use jquery that was previously installed with `npm install jquery`

```
// b.js

define(['jquery'], function($) {
    console.log('B', $);
});
```

But when I'm running `main.js` I've got an error, which states that r.js could not find file named `jquery.js`.

So basically my question is am I missing something or it isn't possible to make r.js lookup for modules installed via npm?

**UPDATE:** Here is github repo with MCVE — https://github.com/sintell/rjs_mcve

Comment: MCVE is a good starting point

Answer (score 1):

Require expects the AMD module syntax, but NPM uses CommonJS. You could tell require (using the `paths` config) where to find the modules, but they still wouldn't be compatible in many cases.

Comment: But accordingly to requirejs docs it could handle node style requires and node modules.

Also jquery could be used as amd module, per it github page:  https://github.com/jquery/jquery#amd-name

Comment: I think you have it backwards; you can use [Require in Node](http://www.requirejs.org/docs/node.html), but not Node modules in Require.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but [here](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/tree/master/tests/node/embedded) you can see how r.js can resolve deps from node_modules. I'm just wondering if I can somehow make it work with `requirejs.optimize`

Comment: Again, that doc is describing the reverse of what you are asking. That is how to use Require _in a Node script_, _in place of Node's `require`_. Unless I'm misunderstanding your question; are you building for the browser or for Node?

Comment: As my question states: I'm building node script, actually I want to use this in gulp task.